# Expand and Collapse All button for any SharePoint List

Tags: 2010, list

I need a feature (shown in images below). The feature is available for Older versions but not for 2010. Is it possible to get Expand/Collapse buttons for any 2010 list?

The examples given below uses this [jQuery](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/jquery-for-everyone-expandcollapse-all-groups.aspx) Script

Comment: Which script added those +/- signs? Is it available freely? If so, you should simply try adding a new CEWP with the same scripts - they might plain and simple work!

Comment: Its a jQuery Script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bill Simser has a JQuery script that does this here http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2009/11/12/hiding-the-new-toolbar-button-in-sharepoint-with-jquery.aspx

It could be easily ported once same elements have been identified.

Comment: @saumilm - Did you port it?  How did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Group By" option when modifying or creating a view on the list. This will create these expand/collapse nodes.

[image: List View - Group By option]

Comment: You are right, but I believe he meant the little +/- buttons on the toolbar which most likely are added via Javascript.

Comment: Oh wow lol, I didn't even see those in the picture.

Comment: @C.Marius That's Correct! I wanted +/- buttons so that I can expand or collapse all groups by one click. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, of course, update your Question with location of the script if that is available freely, or you shall most likely receive alternatives

Comment: Updated the question with the code!

Comment: There is a problem with this grouping in 2010 - if you try to use it with inline editing, the group keeps collapsing so that the process of editing inline becomes: 1) click-to-expand-group, 2) click the edit button (the group automatically collapses!!!!!, 3) click to expand group (ah, now the field can be seen in edit mode.   Problem is that sometimes when you expand the group, a different group expands.  PITA if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I've solved this, if you've used the "Group By" feature for the list.  I add this code, perhaps, in a CEWP:

```
//This will auto-expand a list that has grouping set on it.
//set collapsemode to 1 to collapse everything; set it to 0 to expand everything.
//http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73652/problem-with-jquery-function-for-expanding-grouped-lists/73695#73695
function AutoExpandList(collapsemode){
    if (collapsemode) {
        $("img[src$='minus.gif']:visible").parent().click();
    } else {
        $("img[src$='plus.gif']:visible").parent().click();
    }
}
```

Then, if I want expand and contract buttons, I add some buttons...

```
<a href="#" id="expandall">Expand All</a>
<a href="#" id="contractall">Contract All</a>
```

and then add this jQuery code to attach a function to those "buttons":

```
//set up expand and contract buttons for certain lists
function setupcontractors(){
    $("#contractall").click(function(){
        AutoExpandList(1);
    });
    $("#expandall").click(function(){
        AutoExpandList(0);
    });
}
```

Now I've got two clickable "buttons" that will expand or contract all the groups in the list.  It works for any list.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function expandAll() {
        $('img[alt="expand"]').click();
    }

    function collapseAll() {
        $('img[alt="collapse"]').click();
    }

    var expandButton = "<a href='#' onClick="

    +'"' + "this.href='javascript:expandAll()'"

    + '">&nbsp;<img title="expand all groups" style="border:none;" alt="expand all" src="/_layouts/images/collapseplus.gif"></a>';

    var collapseButton = "<a href='#' onClick="

    +'"' + "this.href='javascript:collapseAll()'"

    + '">&nbsp;<img title="expand all groups" style="border:none;" alt="collapse all" src="/_layouts/images/collapseminus.gif"></a>';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("......").append(expandButton).append(collapseButton);
    });
</script>
```

This should do.